# Is it possible to end in git detached head from pull, push, fetch or rebase?

Tags: windows, git, macos, python-2.7, gitpython

I have a python server application that handles a git repository. It creates commits and switches branches to apply changes locally and then pushes them to the remote repo.

For some reason, users that run the server on Mac see their repository ending up in a `detached HEAD` state. This has never happen for users running the server on Windows machines.

The tool uses GitPython, and there is no service that does a checkout to a specific commit SHA, it only switches to branch names. It does perform `git pull --rebase` and `git push`.

Is there a way to end up in the `detached HEAD` state by performing pulls with rebase, fetches or pushes, or any other way that is not a checkout to a commit SHA?

Comment: If you checkout a renote branch or a tag you end up in `detached HEAD` state, just to name 2 that don't deal with revision IDs

Comment: pulling a superproject will most likely put the subrepos in detached head. The answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

An *incomplete* rebase—one that stops due to a merge conflict, typically, though any kind of error, such as a permissions problem, will also do it—will leave you in the middle of the rebase.  Rebase itself uses detached-HEAD mode, so you will have a detached HEAD here.  That's the most likely source of the problem.

(As [eftshift0 noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165595/is-it-possible-to-end-in-git-detached-head-from-pull-push-fetch-or-rebase#comment113466446_64165595), passing a tag name to `git checkout`, or any name that's not a branch name, also results in a detached HEAD.)

Comment: By error you mean a merge conflict? Is there a way to reproduce that in order to make a test and ensure it resolves the problem?

Comment: "Error" was the wrong term (I'll change it) but a merge conflict would suffice, yes. Anything that makes the rebase stop suffices. An actual error would do this as well, but those are pretty rare.

Comment: To reproduce it, set up a situation in which your rebase will encounter a merge conflict. For instance, have the repository contain its own single commit with a difference on line N of some dummy file, then make a different one-line-change to line N in the upstream repository on the upstream branch that the downstream repository will use (whatever upstream branch that might be).

Comment: Interesting. Is there any idea of what can go wrong in a mac that doesn't go wrong in windows?

Comment: macOS (on HFS and similar anyway) uses NFD or NFC (I can never remember which) for file names. This affects names like `agréable`: one form has accent and e as separate characters, the other has accent-e as a single character. So if you have a repository that uses both forms in their UTF-8 name, macOS cannot store this in your work-tree (which produces all kinds of issues). I am not sure about Windows.

Comment: When there are rebase conflicts, the tool solves them by checking out the conflict file from the latest commit and continuing the rebase for example `git checkout <latest commit> -- path/to/file`. You think that might behave different in mac?

Comment: That should be basically the same on macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error was caused by git-lfs not installed by default in the macOS from the work machines. The plug-in failed somehow and ended in detached HEAD state